# Moment.js: Get day relevant to today (i.e. "Tomorrow, today, yesterday, etc")

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

How can I get Moment.js to return "Today" or other relevant terms? I cannot find anything in the docs that cover this.

Comment: moment().format('[today] dddd'); // 'today Sunday' ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can also use calendar function:

```
moment().calendar(moment().add(1, 'day')); // "Yesterday at 9:14 PM"
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/

Comment: Thank you! I had read that in the docs originally but now that I re-read it I may have misunderstood it previously.

Comment: That should be `moment().add(1, 'day').calendar()`.  (Note the incorrect output in your answer.)

Answer (score 8):

I hope this will help you.

```
moment('2013-02-04T10:35:24-08:00').fromNow(); // '3 years ago'
moment().subtract('days', 0).fromNow(); // 'a few seconds ago'
moment().subtract('days', 1).fromNow(); // 'a day ago'
moment().subtract('days', 7).fromNow(); // '7 days ago'
```

Answer (score 0):

Today:

```
moment().startOf('day')
```

Tomorrow:

```
moment().startOf('day').add(1, 'day')
```

Yesterday:

```
moment().startOf('day').subtract(1, 'day')
```